# How to get dependency dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a project that includes multiple Java projects, each one has its own dependencies.

One project is the main project and uses all other projects, but not directly. For example :

Assume that I have three project's A, B and C, A is the main one (the application). A uses B as dependency  while B uses C as dependency, project C has its own external dependencies.

Each person of my team has a permission to download only one project, and will use the others as dependencies as needed.
The problem appears on the team that developing main project, Maven did not download B & C dependencies to their local machine.

These are the pom files for each one:

**A(main project)**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.a.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>D</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.a.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**B:**

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.a.c</groupId>
                <artifactId>C</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**C:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsystemtest</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsystemApp</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.50.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Which configuration should I set in order to get the dependencies of B and C without downloading the source code for each machine?

Comment: Maven resolves dependencies transitively, that is the *point* of maven.What do you mean by "Each person of my team has a permission to download only one project"?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to confuse `<dependencyManagement>` with `<dependencies>`. `<dependencyManagement>` in A and B only sets the version of dependencies without including them. This is why Maven will not download the dependencies of B and thus not of C (except if there is an additional `<dependency>` section in both A and B which you didn't show).